# I am getting $firebase is not defined with thinkester.io reddit clone

Tags: angularjs, clone, reddit

I am getting the following error in my console:
Error: $firebase has been removed. You may instantiate $firebaseArray and $firebaseObject directly now.

My post.js service file is this:

```
app.factory('Post', function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL){
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var posts = $firebase(ref.child('posts')).$asArray();

    var Post = {
        all:posts,
        create: function(post){
            return posts.$add(post);
        },
        get : function(postId){
            return $firebase(ref.child('posts').child(postId)).$asObject();
        },
        delete : function(post){
            return posts.$remove(post);
        }
    };

    return Post;
});
```

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the $firebase service has been deprecated. Try exactly what the console says, directly using the $firebaseArray and $firebaseObject services:

```
app.factory('Post', function($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, FIREBASE_URL){
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var posts = $firebaseArray(ref.child('posts'));

    var Post = {
        all:posts,
        create: function(post){
            return posts.$add(post);
        },
        get : function(postId){
            return $firebaseObject(ref.child('posts').child(postId));
        },
        delete : function(post){
            return posts.$remove(post);
        }
    };

    return Post;
});
```